# Problem in using Ionic.Zip namspace

Tags: c#

I am using Ionic.zip to zip up the files.

You consider there are 2 files in c:\img\a.txt and b.txt. When zip up these files as following

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\a.txt");
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\b.txt");
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\lookup.ini");
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\lookups.mdb");
    zip.Save("Lookups.zip");
}
```

It is creating lookups.zip file correctly. But the problem is content of zip file is...

there is one directory named as imp and it is contains those 2files.

But i do not need of the directory entry only i need files which i added.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the [documentation](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/12070fa7-b8bb-2379-ecdf-f2c077390b4b.htm), use the overload which accepts two strings - one for the directory in the zip file:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\a.txt", "");
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\b.txt", "");
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\lookup.ini", "");
    zip.AddItem(@"F:\imp\lookups.mdb", "");
    zip.Save("Lookups.zip");
}
```

(That looks like 4 files to me, not 2, and in imp rather than img... but never mind.)